# One instance of class can't do two functions at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on ASP.NET web aplication. I'm making it to be MVC and i have a problem with controler class. When i want to populate a drop down list with elements from my SQL database, class is working but only one instance of class with just one drop down list. When i use one class to populate 2 or more drop down lists it doesn't work and VS is not raising any errors. The controler class works, and it can populate drop down list, but just only one drop down list when page is loaded. So to work i have to make an instance of controler class for every drop down list. Please, can someone explain to me why won't work...

this is my DbBroker:

```
public DataTable VratiKategorije()
        {
            DataTable kategorije = new DataTable();
            using (cn)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM KategorijaLeka", cn);
                    adapter.Fill(kategorije);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    //
                }

            }
            return kategorije;
        }
```

And this is my Controler class which is using DbBroker:

```
public void VratiKategorije(DropDownList ddlKategorije){   
            try
            {
                ddlKategorije.DataSource = dbB.VratiKategorije();
                ddlKategorije.DataTextField = "Naziv";
                ddlKategorije.DataValueField = "ID_Kategorije";
                ddlKategorije.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            { 
                //Handle the err
            }
            ddlKategorije.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
        }
```

And this is on Load_Page():

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        KontrolerLeka kl = new KontrolerLeka();
        kl.VratiKategorije(kategorijaLeka);
    }
```

Comment: Post some code as well. In general, people will avoid question without code, and you can get down voted.

Comment: And be more precise about what's happening - "it doesn't work" gives us very little to go on.

Comment: The page can load but class doesn't populate other drop down list. I will post some code.

Comment: Well, how can you possibly guess what is going wrong when you swallow the errors? (catch Ex with empty block) Truely, you don't think it's better to let us guess the Exception than for the runtime to tell you the true and accurate exception?

Comment: I used System.Console() in every exception. I just didn't copy. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. Ok, so when you use using() function with adapter there is no closing connection to database so when same function is called it can't populate another drop down list because the connection from last drop down list function is not closed. Insted of that code in DbBroker i used this and it worked! "pokreniDBtransakciju()" use cn (sql connection string) and after taking Record Set from database the connection is closed using "cn.Close()" which solved all problems.

DbBroker:

```
 public DataTable Uzmi()
        {
            DataTable dt;
            dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            try
            {
                sc.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM KategorijaLeka";
                sc.Connection = pokreniDBTransakciju();
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = sc.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(reader);
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GRESKA!!!" + e);
                return null;
            }
            return dt;
        }
```